# Connection refused, but port is open

Tags: router, ip, port-forwarding, connection, netcat

My Idea was to make netcat-Connection between two devices in different LAN; Now I looked in settings of WiFi-Router and created a port forwarding; port 4004 of router should now be able to connect me to the port 9009 on my device; on that device I started `nc -l -p 9009` to open the port for listening;
Now from extern I try to connect: `nc <router-ip> 4004`
All I get, is *connection refused* -_-

PS: trying on *[canyouseeme.org](http://canyouseeme.org)* told me the port is open ¯\_(シ)_/¯

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After that long time I came back and saw my question. Well. It was because of "Hairpin". It is sometimes not allowed by the router. That means I can't connect to the router from it's external address being in the LAN from the router. Back then I did not think there could be a difference of being in the same network.

For me, VPN solved it.